# Running Scripts on start up on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, cron, node.js, ubuntu-18.04, python3

I know similar questions have been asked before. I am running a Google Cloud server with Ubuntu 18.04. My problem is that I can't get a `cron` job to run my bash scripts at reboot.

My current `crontab` setup looks like

```
@reboot /home/username/server/start-server.sh
@reboot /home/username/bot/start-server-bot.sh
```

These two shell scripts contain the following:

start-server.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo screen -dmSL serverName node run-server.js
```

start-server-bot.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash 
sudo screen -dmSL botName python3 bot.py
```

I am trying to start these two scripts upon reboot of my Ubuntu server, in separate screen processes as well. However, once I reboot the server, there are no screen processes present. I have edited the `crontab` under the root user. So there are root permissions there. I have also run `chmod 777` on both shell scripts and made them executable as well.

What am I doing wrong here? Both scripts work when executed manually.

Comment: I believe that you should probably have each ``@reboot`` on a separate line. Also, if the scripts are going to be run by the root user, they don’t need to use ``sudo``.

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/

Comment: @Scott, they are on seperate lines. That was an error in my post. Sorry about that. I will fix that.